# Qual diferença entre htm, html, dhtml e ghtml?

Tags: html, terminologia

Navegando na nossa "*deepweb*", percebi algumas variações de extensão da URL no navegador em algumas páginas simples. Por exemplo no website do [*globo.com*](http://www.globo.com/), que para alguns casos é `.ghtml`. Por algum momento eu imaginei que a Globo tinha criado sua própria extensão, como "globo"html para GHTML.

Veja este exemplo:

> http://g1.globo.com/mundo/noticia/neta-de-trump-se-transforma-em-estrela-midiatica-na-china.ghtml

Por esse motivo, surgiu a dúvida. Qual diferença entre `.htm`, `.html`, `.dhtml` e `.ghtml`? O que significa cada uma delas?

Comment: Só para deixar claro, páginas do globo.com pertencem ao Surface Web por serem indexadas pelos robôs de busca tradicionais.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo mas tem alguma relação ao arquivo de extensão .ghtml?

Comment: Absolutamente nenhuma. Tanto que é que se tu entrar por qualquer navegador no Globo.com verá que a maioria das extensões das páginas do G1 são `.ghtml`, as quais tem layout levemente diferente das `.html`, em notícias regionais.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Cada um usa a extensão do arquivo que quiser. Não há um padrão universal.

O mais comum é `.html`. Em Windows algumas pessoas preferem usar `.htm`, mas não muda nada.

O `.dhtml` pode ser uma extensão que indica conteúdo dinâmico para eles, algo que o servidor HTTP está configurado pra processar de forma diferente chamando uma aplicação que vai interpretar aquilo e gerar uma saída. Pode ser que essa página seja gerada por PHP, por exemplo, então ao invés deles colocarem `.php` nos arquivos colocaram `.dhtml`.

O `ghtml` deve ser algum outro tipo de página que exige que outra aplicação seja chamada para interpretá-la. Provavelmente algo que a Globo escolheu com o `g` só porque ficava bonitinho.

Mesmo o `.html` pode estar chamando uma aplicação pra processar. Há 20 anos atrás eu fazia isto e os "webmasters" da época ficavam intrigados como eu conseguia fazer uma página ser "dinâmica" sendo que ela é um "HTML padrão".

Nem precisa ter extensão, a extensão não determina nada o que acontecerá por trás das cortinas. A configuração de cada servidor é que determinará o que fazer. Alguns mudam até pra complicar para leigos tentarem *hackear* algo.

Isso é o que eu consigo responder. Exatamente o que eles fazem só eles podem responder. Pode existir outros motivos, mas acho que é só para indicar qual aplicação chamar para processar o conteúdo da página.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Fiquei só pensativo por esse ghtml , mas quis colocar a pergunta com outras extensões para agregar mais conhecimento.

Answer (score -5):

O widget ghtml destina-se a mostrar texto HTML de um url ou de uma cadeia de caracteres.
"Exemplos

```
## Not run: 
#   ghtml(system.file("html","gedit.html",package="gWidgets"),
#     container = gwindow())
# ## End(Not run)
```

Comment: Isso aí é **R**?